# how do i get audio files out of collection.json

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, audio

How do i get the mp3 audio link out of this collection.json.
i want to get it so when a user searches in the search box the audio files pop up to play but i'm a little confused

[image]

[image]

Here is my code so far

```js
          const media = 'audio';
          const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
          const output = document.querySelector('.output')

          searchInput.addEventListener('change', searchData);

          async function searchData() {
            let search = this.value;
            const finalData = await getData(search);
            render(finalData);
          }

          function render(data) {
           let html;
          if(media == 'image') {
             html = data.map(result => {
             return `
              <div class="image">
               <img src="${result.links[0].href}"/>
              </div>
             `
            }).join("");
         } else {
          //parse the json 
                    console.log(data);
                    data.map(result => {
                      console.log(result);
                    })
                    /* i want to get the mp3 audio out of the collection.json , how do i do this please? */
                    
         }
         output.innerHTML = html;

          }

          function getData(search) {
            const endpoint = `https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=${search}&media_type=${media}`;

            return fetch(endpoint)
              .then(blob => blob.json())
              .then(data => data.collection.items);
          }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="planet">
<div class="output"></div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only doing a query to get the API data, which is returning a collection of objects, each only *describing* a resource.

For each resource, to get a URL for an actual MP3, you need to do another fetch for the `collection.json` file, at the URL provided in the `href` field. This will return the contents of that JSON file, which in this case is an array of URLs to yet more files, some of which are mp3s. You'll need to then find a URL in that array that ends with `.mp3` and set that as the `src` of an `<audio>` element.

Comment: Thank you @travellingprog your comment helped . i've done the first part, how is the best way to find end with .mp3 would it be with regex?

Comment: yeah, you can use a regex, or use `str.slice(-4) === '.mp3'`

Comment: i'm having a bit of an async issue would you be able to help me @travellingprog